# Should I use the same selector twice in CSS?

Tags: css, dry

Which of the following would be considered best (i.e. better) practice?

```
#anElement {
    font-size:1em;
    color:white;
}

/* other stuff */

#anElement {
    width:100px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

or

```
#anElement {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    font-size:1em;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

In other words: should I *dry* the CSS as much as possible or should I work on typography and general layout separately, maybe even in separate files?

Comment: If you want to keep different categories of styles in separate stylesheets (i.e. one for typography, one for layout, one for color schemes, etc), I think it is fine. I wouldn't want to repeat the same selector for multiple rules in a single stylesheet, though.

Comment: I think if you put them into different style sheet, it would make more sense and easier to find when you need to change certain things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine them but give the properties a logical grouping. There are several ways to group them; you might order them alphabetically or logically (text properties together, margins-paddings together, etc).

See [CSS Property Order](http://www.markdotto.com/2011/11/29/css-property-order/), written by Mark Otto, Creator of Bootstrap.

Also worth noting, in a simple styling example like the one you provided you should ask yourself one question...is it possible that some/all of this code might be reused in other spots on the page? Maybe there are several divs that could use the same styling. Then you should be using a class not an id.

Answer (score 0):

The first option is perfectly acceptable, and certain CSS minifiers will combine them all into one anyway. I'd definitely look into using a minifier, since the first option can produce much more readable/maintainable code, especially if separated into multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple style sheets is going to hurt your page performance. If you want to organize your css in this way, consider a pre-processor such as http://sass-lang.com/.